# How can I add child value, check my code to understand

Tags: javascript

I want to add `billing_details.email` to this but since it is a child of `billing_details` this doesn't work, how do I do this?

**Stripe doc**: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object

**My code:**

```
submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
  // createToken returns immediately - the supplied callback submits the form if there are no errors
  Stripe.card.createToken({
    number: $('.card-number').val(),
    cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
    exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
    exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val(),
    name: $('.card-holder-name').val(),
    // I tried this
    //billing_details.email: $('.email').val(),
    address_line1: $('.address').val(),
    address_city: $('.city').val(),
    address_zip: $('.zip').val(),
    address_state: $('.state').val(),
    address_country: $('.country').val()
  }, stripeResponseHandler);
  return false; // submit from callback
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encase the property name in quotes.

```
'billing_details.email': $('.email').val(),
```

Comment: Does not work. Error from stripe: Received unknown parameter: card[billing_details.email]

Comment: Well then it's a case of studying the request structure that the Stripe API expects. Perhaps that dot means it expects a multi-dimensional array passing. Who can say. (Answer: the Stripe docs.)

Comment: I included the docs for reference, I am unabe lt figure it out. It says it's supposed to be a child of billing_details.

Comment: Child suggests multi-dim array should be sent.

Comment: Okay, are you able to give a example?

Comment: `billing_details: {email: $('.email').val()}`

Comment: I'm so sorry, I just figured out that this is completely wrong. I am not supposed to add the billing_details there, it is supposed to be in my php code. Can you maybe help me here? sorry again.

Stripe_Charge::create(array("amount" => number_format($price, 2, '', ''),
                            "currency" => "usd",
                            "card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
                            // This is what I tried
                            //"billing_details.email" => "test@email.com",
                            "description" => "Desc"));

Comment: Change `//"billing_details.email" => "test@email.com"` to `"billing_details" => ["email" => "test@email.com"]`. If that doesn't work, I'm afraid I don't know.

Comment: All good. I contacted stripe and figured it out. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Contacted Stripe and figured it out, you don't use billing_details for that object, it's receipt_email instead. Thank you.